# Sql Server 2005 - Add partition scheme to a non partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-partitioning

I have a table that has more than 50 million records and which does not have any
partition. But now i want to add a partition scheme to this table. This table has a primary key. But i want to partition it using another int column. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

1. create the partition scheme and partition function.
2. re-create the clustered index on this new partition scheme.